# requirements for running sharepoint on azure

Tags: sharepoint, azure

I am looking to get Microsoft Azure to run Sharepoint on, and I intend to use a virtual machine. Right now, I am trying to figure out what size of virtual machine to get, and how many. According to this web site: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx, I need a web server with 8GB of RAM and a database server with probably 16GB of RAM. But, when looking on Azure's website, I don't see anything about servers, I just see virtual machines, and SQL databases. So this is why I am wondering how many virtual machines, and what size, it will take to run Sharepoint. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create windows virtual machine with 16gb ram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095055/how-to-create-windows-virtual-machine-with-16gb-ram)

Comment: Dude SO is for specific questions.  You are asking questions that show no research.

Comment: I did some Googling and searched through Azure's website, but I didn't find anything. I thought that was a given. Plus I sited that sharepoint website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure Virtual Machines are what you'll want to look at. Windows Azure doesn't actually provision a physical server for you; the entire cloud is virtualized. So: for a software product recommending 8GB, that would roughly equate to a Large VM size (7GB usable, 4 cores).

You can always change a VM's size later, so you may want to start with Large instead of Extra Large (XL), which provides 8 cores and 14GB usable.

Comment: That said: This is really a duplicate of your other question, no?

Comment: Well, in this question I was just trying to make sure there isn't anything else I need to add on, and whether or not I would need multiple virtual machines, if there are supposed to be multiple servers.

Comment: On another note, the site says 80GB of storage are needed for each server, does that mean I need to buy 80GB of storage or 160GB of storage? Or maybe not any at all?

Comment: You should look at [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156003.aspx) on Virtual Machines, which shows what you get with each size. A Large has a 200GB local (scratch) disk area. You can also mount drives (that reside in page blobs), each storing up to 1TB apiece (and you'd only pay for storage used). With a Large, you can mount up to 8 drives. XL allows mounting up to 16 drives.

Comment: Where would the extra drives be found on this price calculator: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full ?

Comment: Extra drives are just considered Storage. Payable by the GB. Different price whether you choose georeplication or not.

Answer (score 0):

If it is to get a production style `SharePoint` farm on the current `Azure` preview, you would need 3 VMs of size large at a minimum: one `AD domain controller`, one `SQL Server`, and one `SP2010 server`.

See my experiences and recommendation for this [here](http://kjellsj.blogspot.no/2012/08/sp2010-azure-on-premises-gateway.html).